# Copy constructor of polymorphed objects in a directed graph

Tags: c++

I have a base class Node for a generic tree:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() {
        parent = NULL;
        name = "";
        rule = NULLRULE;
        childs = std::vector<Node*>();
    };

    void addChild(Node* child){
        childs.push_back(child);
        child->setParent(this);
    };

    void setParent(Node* p) {
        this->parent = p;
    }

    virtual ~Node(){
        if (childs.size() == 0) return;

        // remove duplicate childs
        // since we allow having same child.
        std::sort(childs.begin(), childs.end());
        childs.erase(std::unique(childs.begin(), childs.end()), childs.end());
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
            delete childs[i];
        }
    }
```

And I have derived class NodeSquare, NodeCircle etc... All the node formed a tree in the following class:

```
class Tree {
    Tree() {};
    ~Tree() {
        delete root;
    };
    void BFS(){};
    etc...
    Node* root;
}
```

How do I define a copy constructor for the Tree class? I am passing the tree through reference, that's why I need a copy constructor ...

```
processTree(Tree& t) {
    t = Tree();
}
```

Comment: Look the clone idiom https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor

Comment: _"I am passing the tree through reference, that's why I need a copy constructor ..."_ Doesn't a reference actually redeem you from doing so?

Comment: If I use pointer, yes. But if I use reference, it will call constructor ...

Answer (score -3):

```
Tree(const Tree & copy)
{
 if(copy != *this)
  {
    //to do
  }

}
```

A copy constructif hais this signature , then if the scope you assign your data like a normal constructor the statement is for safety but you can use à list initializer.